# How would I go about finding the weight of something with the square cube law?

Tags: arithmetic

I understand that to find the volume you need to multiply width, length, and height. Im just having trouble using that to find weight. So if im doing this correctly. A balck ant weigh around 5 milligrams. Now lets say we increase the size of the any by 1000. To find the weight all I have to do is multiply 5 milligrams with the volume that the enlarged ant has, right?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If by size you mean lengths are multiplied by $1000$ then the weight should be multiplied by $(1000)^3$ since it is proportional to the volume. So the weight becomes $5\times10^{-6}\times10^9 = 5 \times 10^{3}$ kg